# SQL Like operator in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I had got a task to select search the students those name start with param value and city in the selected value.How can i set in ruby on rails?
i did like this but this is not working
controller

```
 def list

    studentcount=Student.count()
    puts studentcount
    @studentname = Student.where("name name1 AND city = :cityId1",
    {:name1 => params[:name], :cityId1 => params[:cityId]})

    puts 'studentname'
    puts @studentname.inspect
    @students = Student.limit(params[:jtPageSize]).offset(params[:jtStartIndex]).order(params[:jtSorting])

    @jtable = {'Result' => 'OK','Records' => @students.map(&:attributes), :TotalRecordCount => studentcount}

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @jtable}
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
@studentname = Student.where("name LIKE :name1 AND city = :cityId1",
  {:name1 => "#{params[:name]}%", :cityId1 => params[:cityId]})
```

This is a rather dirty solution, but pure ARel cannot handle this case the way you desire. You might want to try the [Sqeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel)  gem.

Comment: Can you help me to write if statement for the cityid==0

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
@studentname = Student.where("name LIKE ? AND city = ?", "#{params[:name]}%", params[:cityId])
```

Comment: This will make sure the name *ends* with the value, not begins with it.

Answer (score -1):

there is a error in your methods, it should be like this

```
  @studentname = Student.where("name = :name1 AND city = :cityId1",
     {:name1 => params[:name], :cityId1 => params[:cityId]})
```